# uploading a photo to facebook page via iphone app

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-page, photo-upload

I am using the new 3.1 Facebook SDK for iphone. I would like a user of my app to be able to choose a photo from his iphone and upload it to a Facebook page's album(this user is not an admin of this page).

if this is not possible i would like the user to be able to post a picture to the album feed.

also, which permissions i need to ask the user to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently a bug in the Facebook api which has yet to be fixed for at least the last year, that when you try to upload a photo to a page, it uploads it to the users stream. 
I have been following this bug report for a long time, and does not seem like Facebook is going to do anything about it. this is the current answer for the question. will update if anything changes.